# Modeling contamination diffusion in a draining container

Tags: computational-physics, differential-equations, diffusion

I have a 250-mL bottle filled with pure water and a sampling line at the bottom slowly draining the bottle to analyze, say 2.5 mL/min. The bottle is on the order of 10 cm high.

Since the bottle is open, a tiny amount of analyte (trace metal) is constantly entering the bottle from the top, at an average constant mass/min. I observe that the concentration of this analyte increases over time as expected, but I'm interested in modeling the dynamics, perhaps for different bottle sizes.

My first thought is to solve the diffusion equation in 1D, but my question is how exactly to set it up. I can't find a problem like this online, as most PDE tutorials teach setting the boundaries to some constant concentration.

1. What should the surface boundary condition be? I thought maybe a Neumann condition where the derivative is the incoming mass flux, but this doesn't work because the derivative just inside the boundary needs to be negative.
2. To numerically solve, I'm just adding a little bit of concentration to the first point each time step as a source. How do I appropriately convert a constant mass flux into concentration? Just consider a volume at the surface with the width $\Delta x$?
3. Ignoring the fact the liquid level is moving, what should the boundary condition for the drain side be? I assume the boundary should be insulating somehow (the bottom of the bottle), and I'll use a negative source term to remove a little bit of concentration.
4. If I did want to include the moving boundary condition, how much more difficult is this?

The effect I'm looking for is that as the volume goes down, the concentration rises faster-than-linear because the same mass into less volume is even more concentration. As a first step, I just assumed that the incoming mass instantly diffuses, and it fits the data pretty well, but I'm curious about how diffusion plays a part.